# jQuery Deconstruction | What does this refer to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does this refer to in the init function below from [jQuery latest](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js)

When a method is called from an object, this usually refers to the object that holds the method.

However in this case the method is called using the new keyword.

Does this change what this points to or does it still point to the object that holds the the method, in this case that would be - `jQuery.fn.init()`

**jQuery Deconstruction**

**jQuery is globalized like this:(line 9422)**

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

**jQuery is defined here:(line 42)**

```
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
},
```

**jQuery.fn.init is defined here:(line 95)**

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
    constructor: jQuery,
    init: function( selector, context, rootjQuery ) {
        var match, elem, ret, doc;

        // Handle $(""), $(null), $(undefined), $(false)
        if ( !selector ) {
            return this;
        }

        // Handle $(DOMElement)
        if ( selector.nodeType ) {
            this.context = this[0] = selector;
            this.length = 1;
            return this;
        }

        // Handle HTML strings
        if ( typeof selector === "string" ) {
            if ( selector.charAt(0) === "<" && selector.charAt( selector.length - 1 ) === ">" && selector.length >= 3 ) {
                // Assume that strings that start and end with <> are HTML and skip the regex check
                match = [ null, selector, null ];

            } else {
                match = rquickExpr.exec( selector );
            }

            // Match html or make sure no context is specified for #id
            if ( match && (match[1] || !context) ) {

                // HANDLE: $(html) -> $(array)
                if ( match[1] ) {
                    context = context instanceof jQuery ? context[0] : context;
                    doc = ( context && context.nodeType ? context.ownerDocument || context : document );

                    // scripts is true for back-compat
                    selector = jQuery.parseHTML( match[1], doc, true );
                    if ( rsingleTag.test( match[1] ) && jQuery.isPlainObject( context ) ) {
                        this.attr.call( selector, context, true );
                    }

                    return jQuery.merge( this, selector );

                // HANDLE: $(#id)
                } else {
                    elem = document.getElementById( match[2] );

                    // Check parentNode to catch when Blackberry 4.6 returns
                    // nodes that are no longer in the document #6963
                    if ( elem && elem.parentNode ) {
                        // Handle the case where IE and Opera return items
                        // by name instead of ID
                        if ( elem.id !== match[2] ) {
                            return rootjQuery.find( selector );
                        }

                        // Otherwise, we inject the element directly into the jQuery object
                        this.length = 1;
                        this[0] = elem;
                    }

                    this.context = document;
                    this.selector = selector;
                    return this;
                }

            // HANDLE: $(expr, $(...))
            } else if ( !context || context.jquery ) {
                return ( context || rootjQuery ).find( selector );

            // HANDLE: $(expr, context)
            // (which is just equivalent to: $(context).find(expr)
            } else {
                return this.constructor( context ).find( selector );
            }

        // HANDLE: $(function)
        // Shortcut for document ready
        } else if ( jQuery.isFunction( selector ) ) {
            return rootjQuery.ready( selector );
        }

        if ( selector.selector !== undefined ) {
            this.selector = selector.selector;
            this.context = selector.context;
        }

        return jQuery.makeArray( selector, this );
    },
```

**makeArray is defined here:(line 637)** // not used in basic selection on an id

```
makeArray: function( arr, results ) {
    var type,
        ret = results || [];

    if ( arr != null ) {
        // The window, strings (and functions) also have 'length'
        // Tweaked logic slightly to handle Blackberry 4.7 RegExp issues #6930
        type = jQuery.type( arr );

        if ( arr.length == null || type === "string" || type === "function" || type === "regexp" || jQuery.isWindow( arr ) ) {
            core_push.call( ret, arr );
        } else {
            jQuery.merge( ret, arr );
        }
    }

    return ret;
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a function is called with `new`, `this` always refers to a newly-created object instance. It doesn't matter in that case that the function happened to be an object property value in a `.` expression.

Comment: Yes. A function's `this` value is always set by how it's called. Don't be so quick to prompt for a reply, others don't necessarily hang around waiting for responses.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist No, it does not return a **function** object.  It's just an object.

Comment: OK, whatever, but a jQuery object is most definitely not a function, which you can quickly determine by trying to call one. Like, `$('body')();` - you'll get an "is not a function" exception.

Comment: `$()` is a function that internally calls new which then returns a function object.  We are now the only 2 people on SO that know this.   See my previous post above for proof of this.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: No, `$()` does ***not*** return a function object. It is entirely inaccurate to say that. The MSDN docs show how to create a function object, and that is an object that has nothing to do with what jQuery returns. `typeof $(); // "object"` A function object `typeof` will be `"function"`. `typeof (function(x, y) { return(x+y); }); // "function"`

Comment: @HiroProtagonist I'm sorry, but you're simply incorrect.  The return value from the jQuery function is **not** a function.  If it were, then one could call it, but attempts to do so fail with an exception, something you can verify for yourself quite easily as I described in a previous commend: `$('body')();`

Comment: @HiroProtagonist and none of the answers to that question you referenced claim that a jQuery object is a function. None.

Comment: When you use '$()' you are are 1. calling a function.  This function then has a single line which instantiates a function object using new - `return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );`  A function object by default returns this and in this case it is even made explicit...

Comment: If it really is a "function object", you should be able to call the function.  Give it a try: `$()();`.  Should work if it's really a function! (Perhaps you're just not clear on what the term "function object" means; in JavaScript it means essentially the same thing as "function".  It is never used simply to mean, "an object created by using `new` to call a function.")

Comment: well...js does not have good terminology...if everything is pretty much an object...then what do you get when you instantiate an object using new....

Comment: You get an object.  There's really no difference in terms of the nature of the object, other than that it gets its inheritance stuff set up appropriately.  I've never heard a specific term, I don't think; just "object created by a constructor" or something like that.  But "function object" means "an object that inherits from Function" - that is, a function. For jQuery in particular, people just call them "jQuery objects" I think.  I do, at least.

Comment: when ever you say `new F()`...you do indeed get something that inherits from an object...which is a function object as you stated...which is what jQuery returns....here it is `return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
`

Comment: Sigh.  Unfortunately, no.  It does **not** inherit from `Function`, it inherits from `jQuery.fn.init`.  That function is used as a **constructor**.  If the object *were* a function - an object constructed with the `Function` constructor - you could call it with the `()` operator.  But you cannot.  **Try it for yourself: `$()()` will throw an exception.**

Comment: The term "function object" means "an object that **is a function**." Return values from calls to `$` are not functions, and so they are not "function objects".